# How to pass ngStyle to directive defined as element in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have custom directive (isolate scope) that uses some template. And I want to fire`ng-style` for internal template.

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1585/) that demonstrates the issue

---

**JS**

```
app.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope, Fct) {
   $scope.Fct = Fct;
});

app.$inject = ['$scope','Fct'];

app.factory('Fct', function() {
    return {
        theStyle: function(value) {
            return {'height': value*10 + 'px'}
        }
    };
});

app.directive('myElem',
   function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace:true,
           scope:{

           },
           template: '<div class="myclass"><input type="button" value=check></input>',
           link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

               }
       }
   }) ;
```

I wrote HTML:

```
 <my-elem ng-style="Fct.theStyle(120)"> </my-elem>
```

but nothing happened.

How can I achieve to make *external* `ng-style` to work for directive template?

The expected behavior should be similar like I'll write:

```
<div class="myclass" ng-style="theStyle(120)"><input type="button" value=check></input>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original fiddle is working with two minor change

- change angular from 1.0.3 to v1.2
- your jsfiddle missed `value` parameter in `theStyle` function

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/9Ymvt/1591/

```
 <div ng-controller="fessCntrl"> 
   <my-elem ng-style="Fct.theStyle(12)"></my-elem>   
 </div>


 var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope, Fct) {
   $scope.Fct = Fct;
});

app.$inject = ['$scope','Fct'];

app.factory('Fct', function() {
    return {
        theStyle: function(value) {
            return {'height': value*10 + 'px'}
        }
    };
});


app.directive('myElem',
   function () {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace:true,
       scope:{
       },
       template: '<div class="myclass">' +
                 '   <input type="button" value=check></input>' +
                 '</div>'

   }
}) ;
```

Comment: This "works", but it causes `10 $digest() iterations reached` errors.

Comment: @Jerrad post entire example where it happens.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work at all when trying to pass through ng-style to the isolated scope: http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/X97kW/1/  Unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @Jerrad http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/9Ymvt/1589/ check updated fiddle, your code just works if you don't mess up markup

Comment: That's not the answer you originally posted, though.